# How do i prevent color change on div when content changes

Tags: html, css, cordova, ios9

I'm developing a `cordova` app and after an update to ios9 I got this strange behaviour.

When the text changes in the "buttons", the "buttons" gets a brown color.
This only happends in ios9. I do not apply any css coloring on select or on change.
the "buttons" are just `div` elements.
I'm using jquery.mobile.flatui.css. Any solution to this stange behaviour?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: @Duki, you have hit two very large issues that just started this weekend. 1) Apple upgrade devices in the field to iOS9. It has broken many, many apps. I've spent all weekend on this. 2) Phonegap/Cordova made an unannounced updgrade. Please read the follow link [Current Tripping Points to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/current-tripping-points.md)